# How do you get large prevews of files like with Apple Finder?

Tags: nautilus, nemo, previews

I have a Macbook Pro and I search for files using Finder and Finder shows large previews of the first page of each file as I scroll through the list. I have not found that feature with Nemo or Nautilus on my Ubuntu desktop computer.

When I have to find files in a hurry I cannot afford to open them up one at a time to see if it might be the correct file.  Does Ubuntu have this feature or do I need to buy another Apple computer?

Answer (score 0):

This works with Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10

Search for the file that you want to preview in 'Files'.

After the search results appear, change the icon style by clicking the icon right next to the search magnifying glass. It will end up showing big thumbnails or 'previews' as you can see with the mac.

Comment: This is Ubuntu feature is not like the Mac.  On the Mac I get to 'see inside' and view the text on the first page (or image if it is a photo).  So . . . a big W (indicating Microsoft Word) is not a preview of the first page.